# Could not find nokogiri-1.6.7.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

So I'm a newb (hey at least i found stack overflow right?) and I'm using Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tut. Chapter three has me input:

```
sudo rails generate controller StaticPages home help
```

and I get back:

```
Could not find nokogiri-1.6.7.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I look at the bundle installer it definitely lists nokogiri 1.6.7.1
AND when I input:

```
bundle show nokogiri
```

I get:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1
```

I'm using rails v 4.2.5 on my macbook pro os x el capitan v 10.11.1

ANY HELP is supremely appreciated.  Maybe I can pay it forward a year or two from now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running that command without `sudo`.  Since `sudo` runs the command as the root user, it changes your environment and probably makes it so that you are using the wrong version of Ruby, or the version of Ruby you are using cannot see the gems you have installed.

**Edit:** As Eric Platon points out, try adding `bundle exec` at the beginning of that command to make sure bundler is loaded and that the right version of Rails will be used.

Comment: Haha, our answers are upside down. Beauty of multi-threading :-) You get the cookies for speed ;)

Answer (score 2):

Bundler is a tool that makes sure the runtime environment uses the right library and versions. Usually, we prepend commands to do Ruby developments, including Rails:

```
bundle exec rails generate controller StaticPages home help
```

`bundle exec` takes a command and its parameters, and run it into the environment defined in the `Gemfile`, found in the same folder.

And as @David Grayson mentioned, `sudo` changes the environment. For security and packaging of your code, it is better to run as your current user (and to avoid the wrath of the deployment team).

Comment: Thanks, Eric! So follow up questions if you don't mind? I'm green, but I am really trying to learn this. So if I pick this up right, every user on my computer has a different environment and anytime I use sudo it impacts my mac system wide? also, I did 'gem pristine --all' and then 'bundle --path' and then the original command I was having problems with worked.  BUT I still had to use sudo to force it to work, and this isn't the only time where I have entered a command and it didn't work unless I used sudo (other scaffolds, for instance).  How do I get around sudo? new user profile on my mac?

Comment: That is another question. On SO, I think it should be either another question (so that other people can search), or linked to another question (I am confident there are plenty similar questions here). I have a few minutes to move to a chat space, if necessary, but the basic thing is `sudo` depends on how you installed Ruby in the first place. It seems you have installed it in a folder where gems cannot be installed or run without root-level access. This is a *bad* installation that will make your Ruby life quite miserable. How about `RVM` or `rbenv` to manage Ruby installs?

Comment: If one of these answers does solve your problem, please mark one as the answer. David's answer was faster and more concise, so I vote for it. Note that our answers are upside down, so I think the "right" one should be the one that addresses the actual problem first :-)

Comment: Thanks Eric.  Honestly, I thought I was using RVM to manage my Ruby install! But apparently not.  I'm going to read up and figure out what I did wrong from the get go=)

Comment: RVM can be installed as `root`... Perhaps that is the reason for you to need `sudo` each time. On a dev machine, it is usually recommended to install it for your user only.